# Providing output from one model to another model

Tags: tensorflow

I want to provide the output from one model (f) into another model (c). The following code works

```
features_ = sess.run(f.features, feed_dict={x:x_, y:y_, dropout:1.0, training:False})

sess.run(c.optimize, feed_dict={x:x_, y:y_, features:features_, dropout:1.0, training:False})
```

`c` only needs `features_` and `y_`. It does not need `x_`. However, if I try to remove `x_` as an input, i.e.,

```
feed_dict={y:y_, features:features_}
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,28,28,1]
>        [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,28,28,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Is there a reason for this? `features_` is a numpy ndarray, so it doesn't seem to be a tensor type or anything like that.

Here is the code for f:

```
class ConvModelSmall(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, settings, num_chan, num_features, lr, reg, dropout, training, scope):
        """ init the model with hyper-parameters etc """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.training = training

        initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False)
        self.weights = get_parameters(scope=scope, initializer=initializer, dims)
        self.biases = get_parameters(scope=scope, initializer=initializer, dims)

        self.features = self.feature_model()
        self.acc = settings.acc(self.features, self.y)
        self.loss = settings.loss(self.features, self.y) + reg * reg_loss_fn(self.weights)
        update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
        with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
            self.optimize = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(lr).minimize(self.loss)

    def feature_model(self):
        conv1 = conv2d('conv1', self.x, self.weights['wc1'], self.biases['bc1'], 2, self.training, self.dropout)
        conv2 = conv2d('conv2', conv1, self.weights['wc2'], self.biases['bc2'], 2, self.training, self.dropout)
        conv3 = conv2d('conv3', conv2, self.weights['wc3'], self.biases['bc3'], 2, self.training, self.dropout)

        dense1_reshape = tf.reshape(conv3, [-1, self.weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
        dense1 = fc_batch_relu(dense1_reshape, self.weights['wd1'], self.biases['bd1'], self.training, self.dropout)
        dense2 = fc_batch_relu(dense1, self.weights['wd2'], self.biases['bd2'], self.training, self.dropout)

        out = tf.matmul(dense2, self.weights['wout']) + self.biases['bout']
        return out
```

Here is the code for c:

```
class LinearClassifier(object):
    def __init__(self, features, y, training, num_features, num_classes, lr, reg, scope=""):
        self.features = features
        self.y = y
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.num_classes = num_classes

        initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False)
        self.W = get_scope_variable(scope=scope, var="W", shape=[num_features, num_classes], initializer=initializer)
        self.b = get_scope_variable(scope=scope, var="b", shape=[num_classes], initializer=initializer)

        scores = tf.matmul(tf.layers.batch_normalization(self.features, training=training), self.W) + self.b
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.y, logits=scores)) + reg * tf.nn.l2_loss(self.W)
        update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
        with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
            self.optimize = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr).minimize(self.loss)
```

Comment: How are you removing `x_` as an input in `feed_dict={x:x_, y:y_, features:features_}`?

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40430186/3924118.

Comment: I believe you need to post the code for the network to debug this, because it looks like dependency leaked to `x` even though you didn't intend it to.

Comment: @nbro Sorry, removed x_ as seen above now.

Comment: @PeterSzoldan I added the code. I substituted "dims" for some variable names and dimension values in my function to get parameters since I don't think it is related, and it is a little harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devil is probably in these lines:

```
    update_ops = tf.get_collection( tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS )
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        self.optimize = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer( lr ).minimize( self.loss )
```

By the time you define `c`, `f` is already defined, so when you say `update_ops = tf.get_collection( tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS )` it will collect **all** the update ops in the current graph. That will include the ops related to `f`, `x` within it.

Then `with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):` means "you should do the following *only after* all `update_ops` are executed, including having given a value to `x`. But there is no value for `x` and the error happens.

To get around this, you can either separate the two networks into two different [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph)s, or, probably easier, when you get the `update_ops` you should filter them by scope in the [`tf.get_collection()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_collection) method. For that to work, you should add [`tf.name_scope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope)s to your network classes `ConvModelSmall` and `LinearClassifier`.